# R - Plot two vectors of different size

Tags: r, plot

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
b <- c(4,5,6,3,7,8,5,2,5,8)
plot(a,b)
```

okay sure, that works

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
b <- c(4,2,3,1,3)
plot(a,b)
```

Is it possible to plot the first two items of a to the first of b and the second two of a to the second of b.... and so on.

Any ideas?

And what I don't want to do is..

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
b <- c(4,4,2,2,3,3,1,1,3.3)
plot(a,b)
```

Just because my array is much bigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is! try this

```
plot(a,rep(b, each=2))
```

Comment: @greg121 if this answer meets your needs you can accept it as correct ;)

Comment: @Jilber 3 more minutes than I can accept the answer. stackoverflow restriction